# How to perform a " For " loop in jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to perform a " For " loop in jquery?

Comment: We can assume you know how to write JavaScript for loops, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Or alternatively..

```
for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i) { /*TODO: Magic*/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.each(array, function() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.each() function](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
$('.someSelector').each(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```