# Writing a loop with JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I want to check whether an element has no hrefs in it (ie it is empty) and if it is, to hide the label associated with it. There will be several elements on the page that need to be checked if they are empty so I will need to write a loop. I need help writing the loop please. Here is my code so far:

```
if(jQuery('span.tags').is(':empty')) {
        jQuery('span.label').hide()        
    };
```

Please can someone help me with this code?

This is my HTML

```
<div class="entry-meta">  
            <span class="label">Tagged:</span>
           <span class="tags"> 
            <a href="#" rel="tag">Career change</a>, 
            <a href="#" rel="tag">career change e course</a>, 
            <a href="#" rel="tag">career help</a>
           </span>
    </div><!-- END .entry-meta -->
```

Thanks to everyone who answered this post. Thisis the solution that worked.

```
//Removes word 'Tagged:' if there are no tags
jQuery('span.tags:empty').prev('span.label').hide();
```

Comment: Can you show us some html you would be using this code on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform a " For " loop in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287669/how-to-perform-a-for-loop-in-jquery)

Comment: for the loop, check the .each method in jQuery

Comment: Can you give an example of an empty tag too? It's not clear from your question whether the empty tags have no `href` attribute at all, or simply an empty `href`.

Comment: Hello Town, did you remove your answer? Your solution works perfectly, thank you! By the way, the empty tags did not have hrefs at all.

Comment: @madameFerry: Yes, I did! I re-read your question and thought my answer was too simplistic as it didn't look for hrefs!  Undeleted now so feel free to accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `each` [function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop through DOM elements, and hide each one.

```
$('span.tags:empty').each(function(i, value) {
    $('span.label').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Josh, I tried that but it removes the span.label even if they are not empty.

Comment: @madame: Because `$('span.label')` selects every `span.label` element. See @richardneililagan's answer.

Comment: That won't work because you're selecting __every__ `span.label` in the DOM inside your `.each()` function. You have to find some way to limit the `span.label`s you select to be related to the corresponding `span.tags`.

Answer (score 1):

Based from your HTML, you should be able to pull this off even without throwing out an explicit loop.

```
// something like
$('span.tags').not(':has(a[href])')
              .prev('span.label')
              .hide()
              ;
```

Comment: Thanks Richard but this does not work. I still see the Tagged: label even if the element is empty.

Comment: Did you remember to put your jQuery code inside a `$(document).ready()` handler?

Answer (score 0):

Very easy:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('href') == ''){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Coded up using you example - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/DfM79/

Comment: ... except that that hides the `<a>` elements, not the corresponding `span.label`.

Comment: my bad... let me relook at it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a loop for that.  Based on the assumption that your `tags` span will be empty if there are no tags, this will do it:

```
$('span.tags:empty').prev('span.label').hide();
```

[**Demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/5A7UJ/)

Comment: Simple, neat, and fast.